# How to declare generic type in Xcode 7 for blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, block, objective-c-blocks

I did a simple test for the generic type support in Xcode 7 as follow:

```
@interface MTBaseListViewController <T> : UIViewController

- (void )requestWithBlock1:(void (^)(T data ))block;
- (void )requestWithBlock2:(void (^)(MTListPagingModel<T> *data ))block;

@end;
```

The interface compile without problem.

Then in the class who use it

```
@interface MTTestViewController : MTBaseListViewController <MTTestModel *>
@end

@implementation MTTestViewController

- (void )requestWithBlock1:(void (^)(MTTestModel *data ))block {
}

- (void )requestWithBlock2:(void (^)(MTListPagingModel<MTTestModel *> *data ))block {
}

@end
```

Both methods will complaint about "Conflicting parameter types in implementation ...."

I see `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` method in `NSArray<ObjectType> (NSExtendedArray )` support type infer inside block. So I think it should be my problem that didn't declare the type in right way?